# StackExchange.Redis Timeout Handling

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I've built a basic Redis adapter which works for the most part.

The adapter itself is lightweight

```cs
public RedisAdapter(string connectionString, int database)
{
  _redisConnection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connectionString);
  _db = _redisConnection.GetDatabase(database);
}

public async Task<string> ListLeftPopAsync(string key)
{
  var result = await _db.ListLeftPopAsync(key);
  return result;
}
```

with a simple usage being:

```cs
var redisAdapter = new RedisAdapter("localhost:6379,password=12345,syncTimeout=3000,abortConnect=false", 1);
var request = await redisAdapter.ListLeftPopAsync(RedisKeys.MyKey);
```

I've noticed that I'm getting occasional timeouts like the error below:

```
Timeout awaiting response (outbound=0KiB, inbound=0KiB, 3703ms elapsed, timeout is 3000ms), command=LPOP, next: LPOP PriorityEmailSenderList, inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 1, aw: False, rs: DequeueResult, ws: Idle, in: 0, in-pipe: 5, out-pipe: 0, serverEndpoint: Unspecified/localhost:6379, mgr: 9 of 10 available, clientName: WIN-JN03113EBLE, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=1,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=1,Free=32766,Min=1,Max=32767), v: 2.0.601.3402
```

Everything other than `syncTimeout` and `abortConnect` are default. For the time being, I've changed `syncTimeout`to 5000 since the error appears to say the operation was taking 3703ms (703ms over the threshold), however some errors show operations that took 9500ms which seems a bit long to me. Other suggestions are welcomed!

Any advice on making this a bit more robust for handling timeouts?

Comment: The long time could be acceptable.  The time will depend on the size of the database, the speed of the machine, the amount of memory, and if the database is in a file the speed of the drive, and the amount of data in the response.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?